# Can I get some help debugging this code?

Tags: perl

This is a subroutine which is used to get the past participle of a word. The verb is passed in, split into characters, and then depending on the final letters, an ending is chosen:

```
##Past Participle
sub getPPForBase(){ ##$verb passed in
        my $verb = shift;
        my @verbChars = split(//,$verb); ##Split into characters
        my $verbLen = @verbChars; ##Length of @verbchars, as a number
###PROBLEM HERE:: trying to say last letter is e, second last is i
        if(($verbChars[$verbLen -1] eq "e") && ($verbChars[$verLen -2] eq "i")){
                return substr($verb,0,$verbLen-2)."ying";
        }
    if($verbChars[$verbLen -1] eq "e"){
                return substr($verb,0,$verbLen-1)."ing";
    }
        return $verb."ing";
}
```

The error:

```
[Thu Jun 23 13:47:51 2011] [error] [client ::1] Use of uninitialized value $verLen in subtraction (-) at /Users/jon/Desktop/stanford-postagger-full-2011-04-20/verbTenseChanger.pl line 59.
```

Can someone help me figure out what this means, and how to fix it? (The code runs fine, but I'm afraid there is a hidden problem).

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you need to change it to `$verbLen -2` around here `$verbChars[$verLen -2] eq "i"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you misspelled verbLen as verLen.

Comment: It means one should always `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: I see, I got the code from someone else... From now on, I'll put those at the top whenever I get a new code, and won't just trust it. Thanks!

Comment: It's not just a matter of putting use strict; use warnings; at the top of the code.  Doing so without understanding the code could cause it to simply not run.  Then you'll find yourself chasing down all the globals the original author failed to declare.  Better to read and understand the code before ever trying to run it on your system.  Then if after a read-through you understand it enough to make it strict/warnings compliant, go ahead and make the fixes.  Or just use the ideas from the code to craft your own well-written strict-compliant version.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, you have a typo that is causing your problem. This would not have been a problem if you had used:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Which one always should. So do that.

Also, this is an alternative to your current sub:

```
sub getPPForBase {
    my $verb = shift;
    return $verb . "ying" if $verb =~ s/ie$//;
    return $verb . "ing"  if $verb =~ s/e$//;
    return $verb . "ing";
}
```

Using a regex is in this case, I think, a much preferred solution, as it is much easier to read. Also, when put this way, it is easier to add or remove conditions when needed, rather than trying to sort out all the if-clauses.

Comment: Thanks, Really shortened the code! I guess s/// returns true as well as the changed scalar?

Comment: @Jon Yep. Or more specifically, returns the number of replacements. From [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators): "Searches a string for a pattern, and if found, replaces that pattern with the replacement text and **returns the number of substitutions made. Otherwise it returns false (specifically, the empty string).**"

Answer (score 2):

> my **$verbLen**
>
> ...
>
> $verbChars[**$verLen** -2]

One of these things is not like the other...